# Expand bash array into curly braces syntax

Tags: bash

What would be a nice way to take a bash array variable:

```
lst=(a b c)
```

and turn it into a curly brace syntax, such that it gives a statement equivalent to:

```
$ echo foo{a,b,c}
fooa foob fooc
```

? Naturally, I'm looking to replace the curly braces with the expansion of `lst`. In my specific case, it is not possible (or rather, extremely ugly) to use a `for` loop.

Closest I got so far is:

```
$ lst=(a b c); echo foo${lst[@]}
fooa b c
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recall that if `ary` is an array, then the expansion of `${ary[@]/#/foo}` is that of `ary`, with `foo` prepended to each field. Similarly, `${ary[@]/%/foo}` appends `foo` to each field. Look:

```
$ lst=( a b c )
$ echo "${lst[@]/#/foo}"
fooa foob fooc
$ echo "${lst[@]/%/foo}"
afoo bfoo cfoo
```

You don't need `eval` or `printf` for that.

Like so, you can safely build arrays:

```
$ lst=( a 'field with space' b )
$ foolst=( "${lst[@]/#/foo}" )
$ declare -p foolst
declare -a foolst='([0]="fooa" [1]="foofield with space" [2]="foob")'
```

Comment: How would you do this if the prefix was also an array rather than the constant `"foo"`?

Comment: @BrunoBronosky: Do you mean you want to _zip_ two arrays? in that case, you'd have to use a loop...

Comment: yes, that is what I have done so far. Was just wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use `printf`:

```
$ lst=( one 'two space' t33 )

$ printf '<foo%s> ' "${lst[@]}"; echo
<fooone> <footwo space> <foot33>
```